# List IAM Permissions for User/Role using AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

We're using AWS Cognito and AWS IAM to manage our users and their permissions to access certain resources in our static website built in JavaScript. Before we make certain requests using the AWS SDK we'd like to know what permissions the user has via their Role.

For example in AWS Console we can see the following:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-idp:GetUser",
                "iam:ListPoliciesGrantingServiceAccess",
                "cognito-idp:ListUsers"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using the SDK we've found a method to get the Policies for the User/Role:

```js
    const iam = new AWS.IAM();
    iam.listPoliciesGrantingServiceAccess({
      Arn: arn, 
      ServiceNamespaces: [
          "iam", 
          "cognito-idp"
      ]
    }, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      }
      else {
          console.log(data);
      }
    })
```

However this doesn't return the permissions these policies contain and only returns the actual policies themselves...

```json
[
   {
      "ServiceNamespace":"iam",
      "Policies":[
         {
            "PolicyName":"admin-policy",
            "PolicyType":"INLINE",
            "EntityType":"ROLE",
            "EntityName":"Cognito_Auth_Role"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "ServiceNamespace":"cognito-idp",
      "Policies":[
         {
            "PolicyName":"admin-policy",
            "PolicyType":"INLINE",
            "EntityType":"ROLE",
            "EntityName":"Cognito_Auth_Role"
         }
      ]
   }
```

We haven't been able to find any methods that get permissions for a policy... How can we access this information for a given User/Role?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the relevant SDK v3 methods.  For the above example, you would use `GetRolePolicy` or `ListRolePolicies`:

##### PolicyType: INLINE

[Get[User|Role|Group]PolicyCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-iam/classes/getuserpolicycommand.html): Retrieves the specified inline policy document that is embedded in the specified entity.

[List[User|Role|Group]PoliciesCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-iam/classes/listuserpoliciescommand.html): Lists the names of the inline policies embedded in the specified entity.

##### PolicyType: MANAGED

[GetPolicyCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-iam/classes/getpolicycommand.html) to get the default version and [GetPolicyVersionCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-iam/classes/getpolicyversioncommand.html) to retrieve the policy document.

[ListAttached[User|Role|Group]PoliciesCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-iam/classes/listuserpoliciescommand.html): Lists all managed policies that are attached to the specified IAM entity.